# array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have a PHP problem.

I have this code block

```
$arr_foundits = array();
foreach($its as $it){
    //print_r($it);
    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $it->ID );
    $cats = array();

    foreach($post_categories as $c){
        $cat = get_category( $c );
        $catname = strtolower($cat->name);
            //print_r($catname);
            if($catname=='uncategorized'){
                continue;
            }

            $squery = get_search_query();


            if(strpos($catname, strtolower($squery))!==false){
                //echo 'ceva';
                $found = true;
                $arr_foundits = array_push($arr_foundits, $it->ID);//line 80 hier
                printf('<li><h4><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></h4><p>%3$s</p></li>', get_permalink($it->ID), $it->post_title, get_the_excerpt_by_id($it->ID));
            }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is with the $arr_foundits array, I always receive this error, and clearly it's in array, no way an integer because I declare it there and nowhere else.

Any solution to this error ?

[image: a]
<sub>(source: [imgbin.org](http://imgbin.org/images/13129.png))</sub>

Comment: It obviously isn't due to the error message.. `var_dump` or `print_r` your "array" and post the results

Comment: you should just do `$arr_foundits[] = $it->ID` instead as well...

Comment: This is a text-based online website, please insert text-information as text - not as screenshot. This is important for error messages specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_push` modifies the original array, it does not return the "new" one. It returns the new length of the array, which is an integer. so the second time the loop comes around you are feeding it a number instead of an array. [Docs](https://www.php.net/array-push)

Comment: Yes, offcouse, dunno how that escaped me.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting `$arr_foundits` on `$arr_foundits = array_push($arr_foundits, $it->ID);`. Remove the `$arr_foundits =` as [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) does not return the array but an int.

Comment: Kind of weird really. For example, array_merge returns an array, but array_push which semantically is from the same field returns an int.

anyway, thanks!